# What syntax does Angular's $http.get expect JSON to be in?

Tags: json, angularjs, http

My JSON:

```
[
    {"animal":"dog", "isCute":"true"},
    {"animal":"worm", "isCute":"false"},
]
```

When I call $http.get() with the URL that serves this JSON, I get the following error.  Is my JSON formatted incorrectly, or am I doing something else wrong?

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
  at Object.parse (native)
  at Ib (angular.min.js:13:504)
  at e.defaults.transformResponse (angular.min.js:59:501)
  at angular.min.js:59:262
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at q (angular.min.js:7:264)
  at ac (angular.min.js:59:244)
  at c (angular.min.js:60:458)
  at r (angular.min.js:96:280)
  at angular.min.js:97:417
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a comma after your second object, remove that:

```
[
    {"animal":"dog", "isCute":"true"},
    {"animal":"worm", "isCute":"false"}
]
```

I've found [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to help when diagnosing JSON problems like yours.

Comment: Interesting - I always use trailing commas in both arrays and Objects, so I didn't realize that they would not be valid in JSON.  For those that are curious, according to http://www.2ality.com/2013/07/trailing-commas.html JSON is based on an older version of ECMAScript in which trailing commas were illegal.  Also the JSONLint page seems very helpful - wish I could upvote again for that!

Comment: @Jer Trailing commas' non-validity in JSON is exactly why I don't use them elsewhere.  They're also not totally compatible with legacy browsers.  I tend to use comma-first, which is the best of both worlds.